# Cannot set a Textview using a value from Firebase Firestore.. Any help appreciated (Java, Firebase, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im trying to set a value from Firestore to a Textview. Anything obvious standing out?

The Textview remains blank when the user logs in and views their profile.

```
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + documentSnapshot.getData());

                FirebaseUser currentU = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uId = currentU.getUid();

                 if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                       if (documentSnapshot == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Error Showing the data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "UserID: " + documentSnapshot.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView5.setText(String.format("UserID" + documentSnapshot.getString("Points")));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your upper code means maybe you calling the wrong `path` so please update your code with the `collection path` which you want to retrieve?

Comment: or by the way, your `if` statement doesn't make sense because if your `documentSnapshot` is not `null` then how your second `if` statement will execute. your if statement should be outside that first if statement.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Vishal asked for, and please also respond with @.